# Object into array conversion using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In these I need to add the array value in which pensionname are the same. Add all amount if pensionName value are the same and rechange the array into myoutput array.

My main array:

```
Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
Object
    amount: 2000
    member: "1"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "1A"
    rowId: "row_1"
Object
    amount: 2000
    member: "1"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "1A"
    rowId: "row_2"
Object
    amount: 2000
    member: "1"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "1A"
    rowId: "row_3"
Object
    amount: 2000
    member: "1"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "1A"
    rowId: "row_4"
Object
    amount: 2000
    member: "2"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "2A"
    rowId: "row_5"
Object
    amount: 2000
    member: "2"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "2A"
    rowId: "row_6"
Object
    amount: 2000
    member: "2"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "2A"
    rowId: "row_7"
```

I need the output as:

```
[Object, Object]
Object
    amount: 8000
    member: "1"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "1A"
    rowId: "row_1"

Object
    amount: 6000
    member: "2"
    name: "Peter Andrews"
    pensionName: "2A"
    rowId: "row_2"
```

So I had done:

```
Enter code here
_.forEach(pension,function(item) {
    key = item['pensionName'];
    if (key != "0" && key !=""){
        if (typeof(groups[key]) == "undefined") {
            count++;
            str = "row_"+count;
            groups[key] = {'member' : item['member'],'name' : item['name'],'pensionName' : item['pensionName'],'amount' : item['amount'],'rowId' : str};
        }
        else {
            groups[key]['amount'] = parseFloat(groups[key]['amount']) + parseFloat(item['amount']);
        }
    }
});
```

It resulted in:

```
1A:Object, 2A: Object]
1A: Object
    amount :200
    member :1
    name : "hello"
    name2 : 1A
    id : "row_1"
2A: Object
    amount : 200
    member : 2
    name : "hello"
    name2 : "2A"
    id : "row_2"
```

But I can't push it into an array:

```
var pensionBalance = getPension();
            pensionBalance.map(function(v){
            arr.push(v);
            });
```

So how can I convert it into an array and push or any other method to add the array value?

Comment: An array `is` an object. What do you mean, you want to loose named properties?

Comment: `array + ""` should give you exactly what you want, `[Object, object]`

Comment: please add you source array/object in plain text/as literal

Comment: it seems to be overcomplicated ... strange structure

Comment: Any one willing to have a skype chat @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz Whether u need extra summary

Comment: I suppose that you are trying to group objects by same `pensionName` property, sum up their `amount` ... but `member` property is contradicting. Why? Why the second object in the final output should have `member: "5"` , why not `6` or `1`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest . Sry i  had changed some points in question

Comment: Maybe post the code of where you are defining the arrays - the source data, rather than the console dump of the arrays, as this is confusing. What *is* the actual source of this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works for you, but I am not sure, what to do with `rowId` property. Take all or just the first?

> Basically this solution works with the `thisArg`, here `this` from [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). `this` is used as a temporary object with references to array items of unique persons in `grouped`.
>
> In the forEach loop, first it checks if the person is already in the `grouped` array and therfore in `this`. If not, a new object is generated and to a new property with the actual `pensionName` to `this` assigned and pushed to `grouped`.
>
> Now we can access `this` object with the key of `pensionName` and add the `amount` and push rowId to the array for it.
>
> temporary `this` object:
>
> ```
> {
>     "1A": {                       // generated in first loop
>         "amount": 8000,
>         "member": "1",
>         "name": "Peter Andrews",
>         "pensionName": "1A",
>         "rowId": [
>             "row_1",              // added in first
>             "row_2",              // ... second
>             "row_3",              // third
>             "row_4"               // forth
>         ]
>     },
>     "2A": {                       // generated in fifth loop
>         "amount": 6000,
>         "member": "2",
>         "name": "Peter Andrews",
>         "pensionName": "2A",
>         "rowId": [
>             "row_5",              // added in fifth
>             "row_6",              // ... sixth
>             "row_7"               // seventh
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```

```js
var object = [{ amount: 2000, member: "1", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "1A", rowId: "row_1" }, { amount: 2000, member: "1", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "1A", rowId: "row_2" }, { amount: 2000, member: "3", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "1A", rowId: "row_3" }, { amount: 2000, member: "1", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "1A", rowId: "row_4" }, { amount: 2000, member: "2", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "2A", rowId: "row_5" }, { amount: 2000, member: "2", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "2A", rowId: "row_6" }, { amount: 2000, member: "2", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "2A", rowId: "row_7" }],
    grouped = [];

object.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.pensionName]) {
        this[a.pensionName] = { amount: 0, member: a.member, name: a.name, pensionName: a.pensionName, rowId: [] };
        grouped.push(this[a.pensionName]);
    }
    this[a.pensionName].amount += a.amount;
    this[a.pensionName].rowId.push(a.rowId);
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: i had some modification in question. Please review

Comment: It works fine, but can you please explain this functionality.

Comment: Actually, this mentioned grouped data in that grouped data, key doesn't exit.  then how it add the amount into that array.  If this -> mention object, then how the amount had added and pushed into grouped array

Comment: yes ,But when data used to push into grouped array .    grouped.push(this[a.pensionName]); used to push when key doesn't exit ?

Comment: the keys is created in the line above with `this[a.pensionName] = { ... };`

Comment: Yeah, i got it, but while creating key the all data are pushed into grouped array. if already exit how the amount pushed int0 grouped array. Shall we have discussion over a skype

Comment: you can still ask a new question here at stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah, i got it, but while creating key the all data are pushed into grouped array. if already exit how the amount pushed int0 grouped array.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following approach using `Array.forEach` and `Array.map` functions:

```
var grouped = {}, grouped_arr;
// pension is your initial array
pension.forEach(function(v){
    var key = v["pensionName"];
    if (grouped[key]) {
        if (v["member"] === grouped[key]["member"] 
            && v["name"] === grouped[key]["name"]) {
            grouped[key]["amount"] += v["amount"];
        }
    } else {
        grouped[key] = v;
    }
});

grouped_arr = Object.keys(grouped).map(function(k, i){
    var obj = grouped[k];
    obj["rowId"] = obj["rowId"].substring(0, obj["rowId"].indexOf("_") + 1) + (i+1);
    return obj;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped_arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "amount": 8000,
        "member": "1",
        "name": "Peter Andrews",
        "pensionName": "1A",
        "rowId": "row_1"
    },
    {
        "amount": 6000,
        "member": "2",
        "name": "Peter Andrews",
        "pensionName": "2A",
        "rowId": "row_2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
var output = [];

pension
  .forEach(function (v, i, arr) {

    var exists = output
      .reduce(function (a, c) {
        return c.pensionName === v.pensionName ? true : a;
      }, false);

    if (exists) return;

    var obj = arr
      .filter(function (p) {
        return p.pensionName === v.pensionName;
      })
      .reduce(function (a, c) {
        a.amount = a.amount + c.amount;
        return a
      });

    output.push(obj);
  });

output.map(function (v, i) {
  v.rowId = 'row_' + (i + 1);

  return v;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pension = [{ amount: 2000, member: "1", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "1A", rowId: "row_1" }, { amount: 2000, member: "1", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "1A", rowId: "row_2" }, { amount: 2000, member: "3", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "1A", rowId: "row_3" }, { amount: 2000, member: "1", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "1A", rowId: "row_4" }, { amount: 2000, member: "2", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "2A", rowId: "row_5" }, { amount: 2000, member: "2", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "2A", rowId: "row_6" }, { amount: 2000, member: "2", name: "Peter Andrews", pensionName: "2A", rowId: "row_7" }],
grouped = [];
var pensionData = new Array();
var count = 0;
var str;

pension.forEach(function (a) {
  if (!this[a.pensionName]) { 
    count++;
    str = "row_"+count;
    this[a.pensionName] = { amount: 0, member: a.member, name: a.name, pensionName: a.pensionName, rowId: str };
     pensionData.push(this[a.pensionName]);
  }
 this[a.pensionName].amount += a.amount;
}, {});
```

The output:

```
[
 {
    "amount": 8000,
    "member": "1",
    "name": "Peter Andrews",
    "pensionName": "1A",
    "rowId": "row_1"
 },
 {
    "amount": 6000,
    "member": "2",
    "name": "Peter Andrews",
    "pensionName": "2A",
    "rowId": "row_2"
 }
]
```